# Sierpinski's Triangle Pygame Recursive Function

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I've been working on a tutorial paper where we are meant to create a Sierpinksi Triangle. which supposed to look like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajWUQ.png)

And I don't know what is wrong with my code cause its not like what the output that i wanted. Can someone please help me fix this?

I couldn't make my function work.

```
import sys, pygame


# a function that will draw a right-angled triangle of a given size anchored at a given location
def draw_triangle(screen, x, y, size):
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, white, [[x, y], [x + size, y], [x, y - size]])

############################################################################################# 
# Define a function that will draw Sierpinski's Triangle at a given size anchored at a given location
# You need to update this function 
# currently only one triangle is drawn

def sierpinski(screen, x, y, size):
    mini_size = 10

    if size < mini_size:
        return draw_triangle(screen, x, y, size)
    else:

        new_size = int(size * 0.5)
        sierpinski(screen, x + new_size, y, new_size)
        sierpinski(screen, x, y - new_size, new_size)
        sierpinski(screen, x - new_size, y + new_size, new_size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need some changes:

```
def sierpinski(screen, x, y, size):
    mini_size = 10

    if size < mini_size:
        return draw_triangle(screen, x, y, size) # give white colour
    else:
        new_size = int(size * 0.5)
        #draw_triangle(screen, x, y, size) # give black colour colour
        sierpinski(screen, x + new_size, y, new_size) # here location x,y
        sierpinski(screen, x, y - new_size, new_size) 
        sierpinski(screen, x - new_size, y + new_size, new_size)# here x+new_size,y
```

It looks like:

```
def sierpinski(screen, x, y, size):
    mini_size = 10
    if size < mini_size:
        return draw_triangle(screen, x, y, size)
    else:
        new_size = int(size*0.5)
        draw_triangle1(screen, x, y, new_size)
        sierpinski(screen,x, y,new_size)
        sierpinski(screen, x, y-new_size,new_size)
        sierpinski(screen, x+new_size, y,new_size )
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have to do this for the course i'm doing at Massey Uni. The function I used was:

```
def sierpinski(screen, x, y, size, MinSize):

    if size <= MinSize:
        #creating a new triangle object
        T = triangle(x, y, size, white)
        #drawing the triangle to screen
        T.draw(screen)
        #adding the triangle to the array
        Triangle.append(T)
    else:
        #halving the size and then recalling this function
        size = int(size / 2)
        sierpinski(screen, x, y, size, MinSize)
        sierpinski(screen, x + size, y, size, MinSize)
        sierpinski(screen, x, y - size, size, MinSize)
```

I used a class for each triangle instead of an array, and used a variable to store all the objects for the sierpinski triangle so that i could redraw it if i needed to.
Make sure you only call the sierpinski function once (call it before you're main loop).
My final script was:

```
import sys, pygame, pyautogui


# Triangle class, Takes x, y, size, and color#
class triangle():
    def __init__(self, x, y, size, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.color = color

    # Draws the triangle to the display, then updates the screen. Takes screen.
    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, self.color,
                            [[self.x, self.y], [self.x + self.size, self.y], [self.x, self.y - self.size]])
        pygame.display.flip()

    # Allows for the object to be printed. Used for testing
    def __str__(self):
        return "X: {}, Y: {}, Size: {}".format(self.x, self.y, self.size)


#############################################################################################
# Define a function that will draw Sierpinski's Triangle at a given size anchored at a given location
# You need to update this function
# currently only one triangle is drawn
#############################################################################################

#Sierpinski function, requires a surface(screen), x, y (anchor point), size (outer triangle), and minimum size.
def sierpinski(screen, x, y, size, MinSize):

    if size <= MinSize:
        #creating a new triangle object
        T = triangle(x, y, size, white)
        #drawing the triangle to screen
        T.draw(screen)
        #adding the triangle to the array
        Triangle.append(T)
    else:
        #halving the size and then recalling this function
        size = int(size / 2)
        sierpinski(screen, x, y, size, MinSize)
        sierpinski(screen, x + size, y, size, MinSize)
        sierpinski(screen, x, y - size, size, MinSize)

#############################################################################################

# Initialize the game engine
pygame.init()

# Define the colors we will use in RGB format
black = [0, 0, 0]
white = [255, 255, 255]
blue = [0, 0, 255]
green = [0, 255, 0]
red = [255, 0, 0]

# Array for the triangles
Triangle = []

# sets the height and width of the screen using pyautogui
Screen_Width, Screen_Height = pyautogui.size()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Screen_Width, Screen_Height),pygame.FULLSCREEN)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Draw Sierpinski's triangle at a given size anchored at a given location
# Only needs to be called once#

sierpinski(screen, 0, 800, 800, 2)

while True:
    # This limits the while loop to a max of 10 times per second.
    # Leave this out and we will use all CPU we can.
    clock.tick(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
            break  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    #Getting key input
    Key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #if the user presses the escape key, the loop breaks, and program closes
    if Key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        break


# Tidy up
pygame.quit()
```